# Bash redirection in a script in parallel

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, stdout

I have a bash script with a loop of processes that I want to run in parallel:

```
for i in {1..5}
do
echo Running for simulation $i
python script.py $i > ./outlogs/$i.log 2>&1 &
done
```

But when I do this the file redirection doesn't work, so `$i.log` just stays empty. The redirection only works when I do not use the `&` at the end, but then the script waits for each process to finish before starting the next one, which I don't want.

I tried a solution using `script -c`, but this does not update in realtime, only once the process ends. Does anyone have better suggestions, where the file redirection works in this script but it still updates in realtime?

Comment: what exactly you mean by redirect? you launch 5 process, each out them has std(in|out|err)

Comment: Yes as in redirect the stdout & stderr of each subprocess to the file ./outlogs/$i.log

Comment: Your scripts looks ok, I mean both stdout and strerr for each subprocess go to different files, 1 to 1.log, 2 to 2.log etc.

Comment: I mean I changed your python script to very simple one like #!/bin/bash
echo "to error" 1>&2;
sleep 5
echo $*;   and it works correctly

Comment: Aah okay, looks like it's python's buffering that's the problem rather than bash itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need simply add `-u` option so it will look like this:

```
python -u script.py $i > ./outlogs/$i.log 2>&1 &
```

Option `-u` is for unbuffered binary stdout and stderr